# python reportlab give format to Listitem

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

How to add characters to a numbered reportlab PDF in python. Examples:

1. First element
2. This is the second element

Other:
  a) First item
  b) Second one

How to add ".", ")", "-",  I had run:

```
Myitems.append(ListFlowable([  
    ListItem(Paragraph("text", styleLeft),  
    leftIndent=20)],   
    bulletType='a', leftIndent=20, start=1))
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find this documented anywhere. The answer seems to be buried in the source: [reportlab.platypus.flowables._bulletFormat](https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab/src/9bb6ebf1b8473e3dc11740cbdce0d5dc1a1afae2/src/reportlab/platypus/flowables.py#lines-1931).

```
def _bulletFormat(value,type='1',format=None):
    if type=='bullet':
        s = _bulletNames.get(value,value)
    else:
        s = _type2formatter[type](int(value))

    if format:
        if isinstance(format,strTypes):
            s = format % s
        elif isinstance(format, collections.Callable):
            s = format(s)
        else:
            raise ValueError('unexpected BulletDrawer format %r' % format)
    return s
```

From which we can work out that we can provide `bulletFormat` parameter to the `ListFlowable` that will be applied to the value of the number/letter in an ordered list. We can also work out that parameter can be a Callable (i.e. function) taking a single string parameter, and returning a single string value, or we can provide a string for %-formatting. I'm not a fan of the latter but it will probably do just fine for the majority of cases.

I leave you with the following script which demonstrates what you need. I've added a screenshot of what this produces for me in my environment. You may need to play with fonts and styles etc.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import unicodedata
from pathlib import Path
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, ListFlowable, Spacer
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet

output = Path.cwd() / Path(__file__).with_suffix(".pdf").name
doc = SimpleDocTemplate(str(output))

styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
normal = styles["Normal"]
body = styles["BodyText"]
h2 = styles["Heading2"]

def second_tetration(value: str):
    try:
        n = int(value)
        try:
            # Only works up to 9 (i.e. single digits)
            exponent = unicodedata.lookup(unicodedata.name(str(n)).replace("DIGIT", "SUPERSCRIPT"))
        except KeyError:
            exponent = None

        if exponent is None:
            return f"{n}^{n} = {n ** n}"
        else:
            return f"{n}{exponent} = {n ** n}"
    except ValueError:
        return value

story = [
    Paragraph("Plain", h2),
    ListFlowable(
        [Paragraph(s, normal) for s in ["One", "Two", "Three"]]
    ),

    Paragraph("With a Full Stop (Period)", h2),
    ListFlowable(
        [Paragraph(s, normal) for s in [
            "First element",
            "This is the second element",
        ]],
        bulletFormat="%s.",  # ←
    ),

    Paragraph("With a Right Parenthesis", h2),
    ListFlowable(
        [Paragraph(s, normal) for s in [
            "First item",
            "Second one",
        ]],
        bulletType="a",
        bulletFormat="%s)",  # ←
    ),
    Paragraph(
        "Note that we must also change the bulletType here to get a sequence using "
        "letters instead of numbers.",
        body,
    ),

    Paragraph("Second Tetration", h2),
    ListFlowable(
        [Paragraph(s, normal) for s in [
            "One to the power one",
            "Two to the power two",
            "Three to the power three",
        ]],
        leftIndent=48,
        bulletFormat=second_tetration,  # ←
    ),
    Paragraph(
        """
        Here the bullet is changed to its second tetration; which is to say 'n to
        the power n'. Unlikely you want this, but a demonstration that your imagination
        is the limit here. Note that to really make use of this functionality you
        will have to play about with fonts and styles to ensure whatever characters
        you're returning have glyphs that can be rendered. Hint: grab a copy of
        <link href="https://www.gnu.org/software/freefont/">GNU FreeFont</link>.
        """,
        body,
    ),

]
doc.build(story)
```

[image: Screenshot of preceding code]

([Code as a Gist](https://gist.github.com/samuelharmer/598b3a532f7c3869a376c3d1a84f2571))

Comment: I cannot *believe* that the ReportLab docs are so bad that they completely fail to mention ALL of this. Thank you so much for doing the needful to supplement RL's docs in this way.

Answer (score 0):

This might be out of context answer here, but I came to this QA post while searching for how to format bullets. While I was struggling to create bullets in pdf and the text I was getting was from an LLM(considering that you know how LLM returned text looks). So the following code resolved all of my problems.

This code basically solves two problems.

1. It returns html/markdown text (if needed)
2. It converts that html/markdown text to pdf and with proper formatting.

So, you can use `markdown2` library along with `pdfkit` to convert text to html and then html to pdf. here is the code:

```
import markdown2
import pdfkit
def create_pdf(text):
   output_file = open("file.pdf", 'a+')
   html_content = markdown2.markdown(text)
   options = {
    'page-size': 'A4',
    'margin-top': '0.75in',
    'margin-right': '0.75in',
    'margin-bottom': '0.75in',
    'margin-left': '0.75in',
   }
   # print(html_content)
   # Convert HTML to PDF
   pdfkit.from_string(html_content, output_file, options=options)
```

remember to install `wkhtmltopdf` binaries on your system.

Answer (score -1):

```
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_JUSTIFY
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet

doc = SimpleDocTemplate("form_letter.pdf",pagesize=letter,
                        rightMargin=72,leftMargin=72,
                        topMargin=72,bottomMargin=18)

styles = getSampleStyleSheet()

Story=[]

ptext = '''
<seq>) </seq>Some Text<br/>
<seq>) </seq>Some more test Text
'''
Story.append(Paragraph(ptext, styles["Bullet"]))

doc.build(Story)
```

Comment: A direct solution is welcome, but please ensure you add context around it so your fellow users will understand how it solves the problem

Comment: -1 From what I'm reading of the question, this isn't right. The OP is not asking how to render bullets, but how to include formatting with an ordered list.